# MySQL: не выполняется WHERE-условие AND

Tags: mysql

В базе есть таблица pvt_messages  такого вида,

```
SELECT * FROM pvt_messages WHERE id_user_from=2 AND user_from='qwerty'
```

почему запрос не возвращает никаких результатов?

таблица pvt_messages

```
id_user_from    name_user_from      user_from
   1                 name2              qwerty  
   2                 name3              qwerty1 
   2                 name3              qwerty1 
   2                 name3              qwerty1 
   2                 name3              qwerty1 
   21                 name              qwerty2 
   21                 name              qwerty2 
   21                 name              qwerty2
```

ведь по логике результат запроса должен отобразить

```
id_user_from    name_user_from      user_from
   1                 name2              qwerty  
   2                 name3              qwerty1 
   2                 name3              qwerty1 
   2                 name3              qwerty1 
   2                 name3              qwerty1
```

Comment: Потому что условию 

    id_user_from=2 AND user_from='qwerty'

не удовлетворят ни одна запись в таблице.

Comment: и как же сделать что бы удовлетворяла?

Comment: все решил вместо AND надо OR ставить

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, зачем вам дублировать информацию в таблице? Ведь у qwerty1 всегда будет id = 2, разве нет?

Comment: @Fike, да qwerty1 id=2, я не дублирую это не полная таблица, то просто сообщения от пользователей

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, это значит, что колонку `user_from` можно смело выкидывать (как из запроса, так и из таблицы)

Comment: Да, очень странная таблица у @Шакала.

Comment: ага очень особенно когда не знаешь что к чему, да билдЭр?

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Условию `id_user_from=2 AND user_from='qwerty'` не удовлетворят ни одна запись в таблице. Для получения нужного вам результат, вместо логики И (`AND`) следует использовать логику ИЛИ (`OR`)

```
SELECT * FROM pvt_messages WHERE id_user_from=2 OR user_from='qwerty'
```